# Get all pages for particular page types

Tags: episerver, episerver-find

I'm using EPiServer 11 version with EPiServer.Find. I have a requirement to fetch all pages for landingPage type and standardPage types in one query.

Can you suggest if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for suggestions. I managed to solve this as below.

```
var results = SearchClient.Instance.Search<PageData().FilterForVisitor().FilterOnCurrentSite()
                        .Filter(x => x.MatchType(typeof(LandingPage)) | x.MatchType(typeof(StandardPage)))
                        .GetContentResult();
```

Hope, it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-CMS/7/Search/Searching-for-Pages-Based-on-Page-Type/) uses searching for pages of specific type as an example so I would recommend reading that.

In your case you would just have to add both page types into the query

Comment: That documentation link refers to the `FindPagesWithCriteria` class. The OP is using "Search & Navigation" (previously known as Episerver Find) which allows for fast searches in an index rather than slow database queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter using `MatchType` or `MatchTypeHierarchy`.